# What textbook and chapters should I go through to study for a probability qualification exam?

Tags: self-learning, advice

In 7 months I will have to take a "Probability" qualification exam similar to the ones shown here:

1. [Fall 2013](http://www.ece.umd.edu/sites/default/files/documents/grad/13F-probability.pdf)
2. [Spring 2013](http://www.ece.umd.edu/sites/default/files/documents/grad/13S-probability.pdf)
3. [Fall 2012](http://www.ece.umd.edu/sites/default/files/documents/grad/12F-probability.pdf)
4. [Spring 2012](http://www.ece.umd.edu/sites/default/files/documents/grad/12S-probability.pdf)
5. [Fall 2011](http://www.ece.umd.edu/sites/default/files/documents/grad/11F-probability.pdf)

Could somebody please recommend the best textbook(s) + specific chapters that would cover all this material?

I would prefer advice from professors of mathematics or at least graduate students of mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

I am *extremely* surprised that those are kinds of questions that appear on PhD qualification exams. The difficulty level seems to be no harder than first or second year undergrad probability courses.

"*Mathematical Statistics with Applications*" by Schaeffer et al. Any book in the Duxbury series is good as an introductory textbook for probability and statistics.

Comment: I second this. If these are the level of the questions, just about *any* introductory text to probability would do.

Comment: I highly recommend Schaum's outline stuff in addition. In one of my qualifying exam, there was a question lifted verbatim out of a Schaum's book.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add my two bits worth.

Looks like a typical Ph. D. exam in social sciences where one is looking for *awareness* of basics of probability. That said, my recommendation would be to get a *tutorial* style book. I would highly recommend

Schaum's Outline of Probability and Statistics, 3/E: Edition 3
John Schiller R. Alu Srinivasan Murray Spiege

It is designed for quick study and great for self study and will be at a level you seek.

I *know* I am going to get into trouble for suggesting a cookbook, but trust me, the book is not as shallow as it first appears.

Comment: It's a qualifying exam linked to an electrical engineering department, which is still surprising to me. If you're engineering, don't they require you to take probability/stats in undergrad, thus making it un-necessary to test you on it on a qualifying exam? 

I do agree that the Schaum's series are great for practice questions if all you need to know are numerical questions not theory ones.